Catalog only mode, product pages not fully cached
I have Magento 2.4.6-p8 in use with Varnish. Site does not use Magento's shop functionality and it servers only in catalog mode and only displays products for customers to see.
All CMS pages load almost instantly thanks to Varnish. Also category pages load instantly.
For some reason product pages load much slower and cause stress to server.
Is there some way to make product pages also fully cached by Varnish?

Please share your full VCL file, and assuming your homepage is part of the slow catalog pages, please attach the output of the following logging command: sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'". This will help me understand your current situation and whether content was served from the cache or not.

What happens here is that your product pages might be excluded from Full Page Cache system.
It happens if product page layout has a block with cacheable="false" tag:
 <block class="Magento\Vault\Block\Customer\AccountTokens" name="vault.token.list" 
     cacheable="false" template="Magento_Vault::token_list.phtml" />

Try finding all product page layout files and see if it has a cacheable tag:
find app vendor -type f -ipath '*catalog_product_view.xml' \ 
    -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'cacheable.*=.*false' {} \;

